# Issue with attr_accessor in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i am developing an application in which Authorization is a model. provider is a field of the model. i have definned attr_accessor for provider field

```
attr_accessor :provider
```

Although its not needed, unknowingly i defined it and faced a issue, when i tried to create a record for the model

```
Authorization.create(:user_id => user.id, :uid => hash['uid'], :provider =>
hash['provider'])
```

the user_id is being assinged the value of user.id(user is a variable in my function) but provider is always being assigned null(hash['provider'] contains a value.

when i remove the attr_accessor every thing works fine and my issue got solved. but why it did not work previously? i am just curious to know what was the issue?

Answer (score 4):

I think you probably meant to define an [attr_accessible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html) (assuming that provider is a field in your database.)

attr_accessor is a ruby method to create an attribute (with an instance variable, getter and setter) on a class (or in the context of rails, a virtual attribute).  You want to create one on a model, which is what attr_accessible is for.

Please see http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/95220 for a more detailed explanation.